# Java-based program will not load anymore

Tags: java

I'm in a class that requires us to use the Alice 3 program. I was running the program just fine earlier today and now it will not make it past the splash screen. I go into the system monitor and it shows that multiple instances of Java are running, with Alice3 running at the top, so why would it suddenly stop loading?

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, but I don't think I made any significant changes to prompt this...

I reinstalled probably 3 times now, restarting in between, but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please run it from terminal and add error message to the question.